# Type signatures that never make sense

Tags: haskell, types, signature, parametric-polymorphism, type-signature

Consider

```
(a->a) -> [a] -> Bool
```

Is there any meaningful definition for this signature? That is, a definition that not simply ignores the argument?

```
x -> [a] -> Bool
```

It seems there are many such signatures that can be ruled out immediately.

Comment: `[]` is not a valid type.

Comment: if you ignore the first argument you have `null` and co - including the first argument I cannot come up with any meaningful no - the problem seems to call for "Theorems for free" ;)

Comment: What is your definition of 'meaningful'?  There are certainly functions of these types, but they will ignore one or more arguments.  There are other signatures that are truly meaningless, like `f :: a -> b`.  There are no (terminating) functions of this type.

Comment: @augustss: (I do understand the usefulness of `const` ignoring its argument) w.r.t meaningful: What intention a programmer would express with it. So it seems only some `bot` like "meaning" could be associated. BTW,  how can your `f` be called in a program to become non-terminating? It needs someone to call it who needs it, who then must be of that type. It works on the toplevel with `let f x=f x;in f 1` though.

Comment: @false You still didn't define what you mean by meaningful. :)  I think you answered your own question about `f`.

Comment: @augustss: I have a definition in my question: Anything that does not simply ignore the argument. This is quite a meager meaning, but better than none. And you somehow brought up non-terminating functions. However, I still fail to see how such a non-terminating function of type `a->a` or even `a->b` can be "smuggled" through given signature to make the function non-terminating

Comment: @false Your definition of meaningful would rule out `const`.  But I think you can refine your definition of meaningful to something that allows `const`.  A function meaningful if ignored arguments are not restricted unnecessarily in the signature, so `(a->a) -> b -> b` has no meaningful definition, because the first argument must be ignored, but is restricted.  Whereas `a -> b -> b` is OK.  If this is the definition of meaningful then `(a->a) -> [a] -> Bool` has no meaningful definitions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Carsten König suggested in a comment to use the free theorem. Let's try that.

## Prime the cannon

We start by [generating the free theorem](http://www-ps.iai.uni-bonn.de/cgi-bin/free-theorems-webui.cgi) corresponding to the type `(a->a) -> [a] -> Bool`. This is a property that every function with that type must satisfy, as established by the famous Wadler's paper [Theorems for free!](http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~dreyer/course/papers/wadler.pdf).

```
forall t1,t2 in TYPES, R in REL(t1,t2).
 forall p :: t1 -> t1.
  forall q :: t2 -> t2.
   (forall (x, y) in R. (p x, q y) in R)
   ==> (forall (z, v) in lift{[]}(R). f_{t1} p z = f_{t2} q v)

lift{[]}(R)
  = {([], [])}
  u {(x : xs, y : ys) | ((x, y) in R) && ((xs, ys) in lift{[]}(R))}
```

## An example

To better understand the theorem above, let's run over a concrete example. To use the theorem, we need to take any two types `t1,t2`, so we can pick `t1=Bool` and `t2=Int`.

Then we need to choose a function `p :: Bool -> Bool` (say `p=not`), and a function `q :: Int -> Int` (say `q = \x -> 1-x`).

Now, we need to define a relation `R` between `Bool`s and `Int`s. Let's take the standard boolean
<->integer correspondence, i.e.:

```
R = {(False,0),(True,1)}
```

(the above is a one-one correspondence, but it does not have to be, in general).

Now we need to check that `(forall (x, y) in R. (p x, q y) in R)`. We only have two cases to check for `(x,y) in R`:

```
Case (x,y) = (False,0): we verify that (not False, 1-0) = (True, 1) in R   (ok!)
Case (x,y) = (True ,1): we verify that (not True , 1-1) = (False,0) in R   (ok!)
```

So far so good. Now we need to "lift" the relation so to work on lists: e.g.

```
[True,False,False,False] is in relation with [1,0,0,0]
```

This extended relation is the one named `lift{[]}(R)` above.

Finally, the theorem states that, for **any** function `f :: (a->a) -> [a] -> Bool` we must have

```
f_Bool not [True,False,False,False] = f_Int (\x->1-x) [1,0,0,0]
```

where above `f_Bool` simply makes it explicit that `f` is used in the specialised case in which `a=Bool`.

The power of this lies in that we do not know what the code of `f` actually is. We are deducing what `f` must satisfy by only looking at its polymorphic type.

Since we get types from type inference, and we can turn types into theorems, we really get "theorems for free!".

## Back to the original goal

We want to prove that `f` does not use its first argument, and that it does not care about its second list argument, either, except for its length.

For this, take `R` be the universally true relation. Then, `lift{[]}(R)` is a relation which relates two lists iff they have the same length.

The theorem then implies:

```
forall t1,t2 in TYPES.
 forall p :: t1 -> t1.
  forall q :: t2 -> t2.
   forall z :: [t1].
    forall v :: [t2].
     length z = length v ==> f_{t1} p z = f_{t2} q v
```

Hence, `f` ignores the first argument and only cares about the length of the second one.

QED

Answer (score 7):

You can't do anything interesting with `x` on it's own.

You *can* do stuff with `[x]`; for example, you can count how many nodes are in the list. So, for example,

```
foo :: (a -> a) -> [a] -> Bool
foo _ [] = True
foo _ (_:_) = False

bar :: x -> [a] -> Bool
bar _ [] = True
bar _ (_:_) = False
```

If you have an `x` and a function that turns an `x` into something else, you can do interesting stuff:

```
big :: (x -> Int) -> x -> Bool
big f n = if f n > 10 then True else False
```

If `x` belongs to some type class, then you can use all the methods of that class on it. (This is really a special-case of the previous one.)

```
double :: Num x => x -> x
double = (2*)
```

On the other hand, there are plenty of type signatures for which no valid functions exist:

```
magic :: x -> y
magic = -- erm... good luck with that!
```

I read somewhere that the type signatures involving only variables for which a real function exists are exactly the logical theorems that are true. (I don't know the name for this property, but it's quite interesting.)

```
f1 :: (x -> y) -> x -> y
-- Given that X implies Y, and given that X is true, then Y is true.
-- Well, duh.

f2 :: Either (x -> y) (x -> z) -> x -> Either y z
-- Given that X implies Y or X implies Z, and given X, then either Y or Z is true.
-- Again, duh.

f3 :: x -> y
-- Given that X is true, then any Y is true.
-- Erm, no. Just... no.
```

Comment: Discussion [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65212/discussion-on-answer-by-mathematicalorchid-type-signatures-that-never-make-sense).